# Checking the goodness of a probability model

Tags: modeling, goodness-of-fit

I have a data set that I claim is adequately modeled by a probability distribution, or more generally a family of probability distributions. How do you decide that the model is good/useful/correct under the stipulation that you can only refer to this data set?

For concreteness, the data set could be [-3,2,1,0,10020] and the proposed model for an individual data point is a Normal(theta,1) where theta is real; additionally, the data points are independent.

Comment: When you say "is modeled", it is only modeled that way if someone *does* use that model (and doesn't speak to its suitability). Do you mean something like "may be reasonably modeled"? As for deciding "good/useful" that depends on your criteria ("correct" you almost certainly won't have and couldn't prove if you did; models are generally useful approximations at best). So what would make it "good" or "useful" for you?

Comment: Surely a model can be used which is not suitable? "May be *reasonably* modeled" connotes a criterion for correctness, which is something I am after. I am not sure what would make a probability model "good" or "useful" for me, but wonder how others would approach defining a criterion for goodness (hence this question).

Comment: That's my point! You say "I claim is modeled". Either someone used the model or they didn't -- no need to claim it is a fact, you can just state whether someone modeled the distribution that way -- so did they or didn't they? Was that model used or not?

Comment: Yes, the model was used.

Comment: Then there's no need to say you claim it. Just state it -- otherwise it looks like you're trying to say something else.

Answer (score 2):

You can chart a reliability diagram (DeGroot, M., & Fienberg, S. (1982). The comparison and evaluation of forecasters. Statistician, 32, 12–22).

Have a look at http://www.datascienceassn.org/sites/default/files/Predicting%20good%20probabilities%20with%20supervised%20learning.pdf

"On real problems where the true conditional probabilities
are not known, model calibration can be visualized with reliability
diagrams. First, the prediction space is discretized into ten bins. Cases with
predicted value between 0 and 0.1 fall in the first bin, between
0.1 and 0.2 in the second bin, etc. For each bin, the
mean predicted value is plotted against the true fraction of
positive cases. If the model is well calibrated the points
will fall near the diagonal line."

Here is an example I could find:
[image: Here is an example I could find]
<sub>(source: [bom.gov.au](http://www.bom.gov.au/wmo/lrfvs/reld_ex.jpg))</sub>

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily, when we fit data to a proposed model, we test whether the model is "adequate" by looking at the distribution of the residual values, and comparing aspects of this distribution to the theoretical distribution that holds under the proposed model.  This process is called "diagnostic testing".  There are many diagnostic tests that you can run on the residuals, depending on what aspect of their distribution you want to test.  Diagnostic testing is done with a mixture of graphical analysis and formal hypothesis testing.

---

**Example:** In your question, you give the example of the observed data set $\mathbf{x} = (-3,2,1,0,10020)$ fit to the proposed model $X_i \sim \text{IID N}(\theta, 1)$.  Now, just looking at this, I can see it is an inadequate model, since the sample data has a much higher variance than is allowed by the model.  This is going to lead all your data points to be classified as "outliers" in the model, meaning that the model underspecifies either the variance or the fatness of the tails.  (In this case, it underspecifies the variance.)

To test this formally, using diagnostic testing, let's suppose that we estimate the unknown mean parameter in the model by the MLE, which is the sample mean $\hat{\theta} = \bar{x} = 2004$.  With this estimate of the mean parameter, the residuals are:

$$\mathbf{r} = (-2007, -2002, -2003, -2004, +8016).$$

Now, under the proposed model, we have the distribution $||\mathbf{R}|| \sim \chi_{n-1}$ for the norm of the residual vector.  The observed norm of the residual vector is $||\mathbf{r}|| = 8962$, which corresponds to a tail area of essentially zero.  (The observed norm is over 40 million standard deviations above the mean under the proposed model.)  This diagnostic test shows that the proposed model is implausible, insofar as it fixed a variance that is too low.  We would reject this model and use a model that allows a free variance parameter.

Answer (score -1):

You can calculate the likelihood (probability of the data, given the model with its parameters). Or log likelihood, which is more practical to compute.

Comment: I see a few issues with this approach:  i) the log-likelihood assumes that the data were generated according to the model, which is what we are trying to determine the correctness of in the first place; ii) a low log-likelihood score can certainly occur even if it were the case the data was generated according to the said model (for instance in the example above I'd bet that the outlier value brings the log likelihood down, but certainly it is possible that the data were generated according to this model)

Comment: also, iii)  justifications of using likelihood based approaches seem to rely on asymptotic properties (for instance asymptotic efficiency of the MLE)

Comment: @user98439
If you assume that the data were generated by family of models - for example N(mean,1), you can express the likelihood as a function of the model, for example likelihood(mean). So you can compare the likelihoods of different models. Instead of doing a MLE, you could express the probability P(model|data) with the Bayes' theorem. That would give you an answer to the question, for example, "what's the probability that the model parameters lie in this range?".